# Throwing an Exception from Conditional Breakpoint

Tags: java, remote-debugging

As soon as some condition in my code becomes true, I want to throw some exception using conditional breakpoint in eclipse.

Is it possible to do so?

(I want to check how my system will behave when this exception comes and also I don't want to make code change, that is why I am thinking to do so using conditional breakpoint.)

Comment: First google hit for "Eclipse conditional breakpoint": http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_set_a_conditional_breakpoint%3F. Can you clarify how that didn't help you?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel I know how to place a conditional breakpoint, but I want to throw some exception from that breakpoint. That is the reason why I asked this question as I am unable to do so.

Comment: Ah, like that. I doubt there exists such a possibility. What is the reason you don't want to change the code? And what stops you from creating a situation where that exception is thrown?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel Actually I can create a file by writing a code using conditional breakpoint. But I am not able to throw an exception. Actually the deployment process is lengthy, that is why I want to achieve this using conditional breakpoint.